# ASP.NET Identity - How to map one-to-one or zero relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, identity

How can I map the following relationship using Entity Framework Code First?

Relationship - Author is the principal and ApplicationUser is the dependent:

[image]

ApplicationUser is a derived class from IdentityUser. Authors can be created first than users, so they are the principal on the relationship. Every user must be associated with an author, but an author may be associated with no ApplicationUser. I've tried to do this with fluent API and with annotations, but I'm not able to say that the primary key of ApplicationUser is a foreign key to Author. Thank you very much!

**Models:**

```
 public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<string> AditionalEmails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PublicationData> Publication { get; set; }

    //User is optional.
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}



    public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Affiliation { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PublicationData> Publications { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }

    //Author is required
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```